# Finding the circumradius-to-inradius ratio for the regular pentagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, polygons

> Find the value of $R/r$:
>
> [image]

I go with co-ordinate geometry, considering the centre of the circles is at the origin, then the equation of the circle becomes as 
$$ x^2 + y^2 = R^2 $$
$$ x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $$

After this I not able to solve this.

2nd Attempt :-

[image]

Comment: Hint: the polygon is a regular pentagon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint:

Let $ABCDE$ be our regular pentagon, $O$ be a center of the circles and $T$ be a touching point to $AB$.

Thus, $OT=r$, $OA=R$ and $\measuredangle ATO=90^{\circ}.$

Hence, $$\measuredangle AOT=\frac{360^{\circ}}{5\cdot2}=36^{\circ}$$ and
$$AT=R\sin36^{\circ}=r\tan36^{\circ}.$$
Can you end it now?